# Data import from MongoDB: duplicate columns

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I'm trying to import data from mongoDB into AWS glue job and then to redshift, but when performing load from mongoDB I get this strange exception, is there a way to fix this issue?

```
AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `column1`, `column2`, `column3`
```

After googling it says that if document contains duplicate column anywhere in schema it will fail, any clue how to handle this?!